# Basic Install of Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Simple question - how do I installed Angular2 in a single HTML file - not using Bower, not using NPM, and not using NuGet, simple script files etc only?

EDIT:

From `Dieuhd's` answer I was able to get Angular 2.0 working using the below scripts -

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference sample on angular.io

https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/js/plnkr.html

Comment: This still seems overly complicated, is there no list of required JS files ANY where?! is it all just "install this package/script to install these scripts"?

Comment: Thanks Dieuhd - are any of the scripts there not required by Angular (like `shim.min.js` or `zone.js`?
Do you think they will eventually have just a combined `angular2.js` file on official release?